# Variable declared and initialized in a switch statement

Tags: c, variables, switch-statement

Why does this program not output 20?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    switch (a) {
            int b = 20;
        case 1:
        {
            printf("b is %d\n", b);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("b is %d\n", b);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Aric - What it outputs won't help. It's not initialized.

Comment: I would suggest you to get a compiler installed. Better install cygwin with developer package and start running the code and you will get answers to all this and will learn faster and better.

Comment: would the behavior change at all if there was no default case?  I don't think so.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that it works at all, since the declaration gets ignored by the switch... although I guess that scope wise it's fair... just bad form.

Comment: Jumping over an initialization statement is valid syntax, but undefined behaviour. Your more sophisticated, modern compiler warns like anything.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because the switch statement jumps to a relevant case, so the line `int b = 20` will never be executed.

Comment: Congrats on hitting the rep cap on your first day here, Rasmus.

Answer (score 8):

Your compiler should warn you about this. The initialization of 'b' is at the beginning of the switch statement, where it will never be executed -- execution will always flow directly from the switch statement header to the matching case label.

Comment: Agreed.  If it doesn't, add the -Wall flag.  If it still doesn't read the compiler manual for the correct flag to enable warnings or get a better compiler (for example gcc).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't output "b = 20" because b is set inside the switch statement and this instruction is never executed. What you want is this:

```
int b = 20;
switch (a) {
    case 1:
    {
        printf("b is %d\n", b);
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("b is %d\n", b);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Gcc throws a warning saying that b is uninitialized when you call the printf()

you have to move "int b = 20" before the switch()

Answer (score 2):

Inside of a switch is a hidden `goto` statement. So basically what is happening is really

```
int a=1;
if(a==1){ //case 1
  goto case1;
}else{ //default
  goto default;
}
int b=20;
case1:....
```

Comment: Inside of an "else" is a hidden goto statement, so basically what is happening is really... ;-)

Comment: Well I could have dropped to assembly and just did `cmp [a],1; je case1` but I figured that was overkill

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `case` labels in `switch` statement are called "labels" for a reason: they are pretty much ordinary labels, just like the ones you can `goto` to. This is actually how `switch` works: it is just a structured version of `goto` that just jumps from `switch` to the appropriate label and continues execution from there. In your code you always jump over initialization of `b`. So, `b` never gets initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
int b = 20
```

is actually doing two things:

```
int b
```

and

```
b = 20
```

The compiler sets up a variable called b when it compiles the program.  This is an `automatic` variable, which goes on the stack.  But it does not assign it a value until the program execution reaches that point.

Before that point, it is unknown what value the variable has.

This would not be true for a global variable, or a `static` variable -- those are initialized when the program begins running.

Comment: how is this relevant? the problem is obviously the initialization is never reached because of it's placement in the switch

Comment: To be fair, he surely just wanted to just say that "b" is still in scope (since it's a compile time thing), which he seem to say is the "int b" part, but just the assignment is not done. So, in other words, the line is not completely ignored.

Comment: The bottom line is, declaring a variable and initializing that variable happen at different times, even though the same line of code does both.

Comment: Aren't statics with block scope initialised the first time their definition is executed? Or is that only in C++?

Comment: In the above code, if "b" is made static, then the output is indeed 20.  If you give it to a C++ compiler, it refuses to compile.

Answer (score 1):

> Compiling with gcc (Using cygwin on Windows) gives a warning message -
>
> **warning: unreachable code at beginning**
> **of switch statement**
>
> and the output is undefined or garbage which clearly says that initialization portion of b is never executed and hence the undefined value.
>
> **Note:** Question can be raised that if the code or line is unreachable,
> then why does not we get the error:
> 'b' undeclared.
>
> The compiler checks for the syntax of
> the program (above checks if b is declared) and finds it correct (b is declared),
> although semantically/logically it is
> incorrect.
>
> Probably in future the compilers may become even more smarter and will be able to detect these kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

The line

`int b=20;`

Is not executed before the switch is entered.  You would have to move it above the switch statement to get 20 output.